# Question marked as duplicate not showing original question

Tags: discussion

I have asked this question [Selecting all fields except only one field in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253994/selecting-all-fields-except-only-one-field-in-mysql) in stack overflow and is marked as duplicate. But when i checked the question it is shown as duplicate but it doesn't shows which questions duplicate is it which makes no sense. Can somebody explain the reason behind this.

Answer (score 2):

That is not so strange since [you](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14253994/4) [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14253994/revisions) the automatically generated duplicate header out of the question.

I reverted that edit so it is back again.

Comment: it should be noted though that the question was closed at a time when the duplicate link was just added to the question body.  If a question is closed as a duplicate now, it would be impossible for anyone to remove.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Good point. I was already searching Meta to see how this could happen. :)

Comment: If I remember the time frame correctly, about a month after the OP's question was asked was when the change was made and the duplicate banner was made a separate element rather than just an edit to the post.